# SQLSRV function PHP Script not working from 443 port

Tags: sql-server, sqlsrv

I have an web application to create some vouchers, basically, it inserts data into a Microsoft SQL DB using the PHP SQLSRV function.

When application is used from 80 (non SSL port) it's working fine, but from 443 with an SSL connection it's displaying ERROR 500.

Thank you

Comment: You didn't provide any information. The HTTP status code 500 means your application crashed. Have you tried debugging? Logging errors? Without any code people can't even guess what's wrong

Comment: The problem is, in the IIS logs, I get only the 500 error

Comment: What about *the application's* logs? Have you added any error handling? Logging? It's impossible to help without any information

Comment: I found out, it's not working only from the DNS address. What could it be?

Comment: Post your code. Add logging. Don't make people guess. For all anyone knows you have `1/0` in the very first line of your site